# What does `overflow:hidden` do in the following example?

Tags: html, css

My question is, if I remove the `overflow:hidden` from this code, my entire navigation bar is going to be hidden, so what does the `overflow:hidden; act in this example.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

li{
  float: left;
}

li a{
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li a:hover{
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please learn to format code.

Comment: In  your case, `overflow: hidden` tells the parent of children having `float` to expand to its children's size.

Comment: Thanks **@LGSon** for answering my question, I completely understand what you explained.Thanks again!.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `overflow: hidden` tells the parent of children having `float` to expand to its children's size.

Also `overflow: auto` will do that, like in below sample, which will make the content scroll in case of lack of space, where `hidden` will hide the same

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

li{
  float: left;
}

li a{
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li a:hover{
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
</ul>
```