# CSS columns and margin issue

Tags: html, css-tables, css-multicolumn-layout

**Update**: The latest code which works in all browsers is located [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/yu00ugft/5/)

I am trying to make responsive columns using pure CSS approach.

I have an issue where columns sometimes have gap/margin at the top.

[(old) JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/yu00ugft/) to try and explore

How to solve it?

CSS:

```
.fx-columns {
  background: yellow;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
    -moz-column-gap: 30px;
    column-gap: 30px;
}

.fx-columns-3 {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}

.fx-columns-4 {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}

.fx-columns .fx-column {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
  background: pink;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fx-columns fx-columns-4">
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="fx-column">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
    <p>Text paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is caused by collapsing margins on your `h3` tags, and this will undo that: `.fx-columns .fx-column { overflow: auto; }` ... or like this `.fx-columns .fx-column h3 { margin-top: 0; }` ... or like this `.fx-columns .fx-column { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`overflow:hidden\` do in the following example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958873/what-does-overflowhidden-do-in-the-following-example)

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` will make columns not responsive.

Comment: Ok, might be, didn't test that, I added it as it resets the collapsed margins ... luckily you still have to more options :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Currently, you're keeping the content from breaking between columns. However, the browser breaks the `margin` between columns, which is causing some of the columns to not start at the top.

Add this to your css:

```
.fx-column {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You'll then have to give the columns a fixed width.

Know, however, that there are a lot of issues with using the column count css property. See this [article](http://zomigi.com/blog/deal-breaker-problems-with-css3-multi-columns/) for more information.

**Edit:** If you want the column widths to be responsive, you can simply set them to `width: 100%` so that they expand as the browser expands.

Comment: The `display: inline-block;` will make columns not responsive.

Comment: You can set `width: 100%` and the columns will expand like they do without being `display: inline-block`. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks for the input

Comment: Thanks. Your approach is working great in all browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/webvitaly/yu00ugft/5/

Comment: this solution makes another issue that 3 cols are displayed as 2

Answer (score -1):

You can set top-margin and top-padding to zero to solve this problem. You can use CSS universal (*) selector:

```
*{padding-top:0; margin-top:0;}
```

But remember universal selector styles will be applied to entire page.

Comment: What if I need a margin and padding for .fx-column, h3 and p tags?

Comment: just add "display: inline-block;" in fx-column like jtmingus said.

Comment: Just use `.fx-column > *` to address only direct child elements of `.fx-column`. In my case this was a viable solution.

Comment: @Gerald doesnt work