list-items and ordered-list have weird spacing when working with columns
EDIT: Update, through the helpful comments I've found the issue is a CSS bug. When using the first-of-type or last-of-type pseudoclass, there is some mystery spacing that appears when also using columns. The only solution here is to avoid using columns with these pseudoclasses. Grid / flexbox or playing with the margin / padding without pseudoclasses is the only solution until this bug is resolved.
I'm using a columns property to break this ordered list and the children list items to create a two-column display. I'm also adding some bottom margin on the list-items to add some spacing between the elements.
In the "three section preview", if you inspect the ordered list, the bottom of the list butts right up to the bottom of the paragraph (as it should).
screenshot showing no extra space between the bottom of list item and beginning of the margin, as intended
However, if the columns are equal in height, there's some hidden spacing at the bottom of the ordered list as seen here:
screenshot showing additional padding at the bottom of the ordered list
This isn't any margin or padding on the list items or paragraphs. You can see I'm setting the paragraph margin to 0.
Now it seems to be caused by an issue between using columns and margin-bottom. If you remove the margin-bottom on the <li> that mysterious gap disappears. But the margin-bottom shouldn't be causing any spacing between on the <ol> parent. To prove this, that's why I have the first "three section preview". Those list-items also have a margin-bottom but, as illustrated in the first screenshot above, there's no mysterious padding.
What could be causing this additional spacing? Any thoughts are appreciated.
What I've tried:
My goal here is to figure out what's causing the mysterious spacing between the list-items and ordered-list. I've narrowed it down to the margin-bottom on the list-items but that shouldn't be impacting the spacing, as illustrated. I've tried using a margin-top instead of a margin-bottom but I still have the mysterious space if there are two list-items within the ordered-list.


.columns {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 3rem;
  column-gap: 3rem;
}

.item {
  break-inside: avoid;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
<h2>
  three section preview
</h2>
<ol class="columns">
  <li class="item">
    Section 1
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 2
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 3
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
</ol>

<hr />

<h2>
  two section preview
</h2>

<ol class="columns">
  <li class="item">
    Section 1
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 2
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
</ol>




Please see [ask]. You need to show code in your post. Also take the [tour].

Try using padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom on the li. Then, you should be able to remove the last-of-type rule.
If you need the margin-bottom on the li, try setting the column grid on the ol...
Update:
Removed bottom margin rule on li (if zero spacing is required).


.columns {
  /*
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 3rem;
  */
  column-gap: 3rem;
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.item{
  break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
}

li{
  padding: 5px;
}
/*
li:last-of-type{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
*/
<h2>
 three section preview
</h2>
<ol class="columns">
  <li class="item">
    Section 1
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 2
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 3
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
</ol>

<hr />

<h2>
 two section preview
</h2>
<ol class="columns">
  <li class="item">
    Section 1
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
  <li class="item">
    Section 2
    <p class="css-r2plao-StyledText e1rr8m5s0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iacul.</p>

  </li>
</ol>




The issue persists in your snippet.

The bottom spacing is consistent on my end. I was able to reproduce the OP's issue and solve it by having the same amount of bottom margin. Was this not the problem?

I can confirm this does fix the issue. It's a different approach to creating the space I need but I might be able to make it work with a little restructuring. The issue, as we've narrowed down, is the first/last-of-type pseudoclass. I still don't know why, but it creates some phantom space that we can't do anything with. I can avoid using it to fix the issue but this is clearly a CSS bug.

Also, you can try "display: inline-block;" on the lis, but you will lose your markers. There are known issues using margin and CSS columns... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020462/css-columns-and-margin-issue

The problem is in your li:last-of-type selector. Because you have multiple lis, it only targets the very last one (in this case, the one on the right column), therefore leaving some margin on the bottom of the li on the left column.
Unfortunately, according to this StackOverflow answer, it doesn't look like what you are looking for is possible. I would suggest using flexbox as an alternative.

Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure why this was marked as "not useful". I think flexbox or grid is going to be the answer here. I was trying to avoid it because this is a small bit of code as part of a much larger react project I manage, and I was hoping it was something small I was overlooking. I will say the answer you linked may not be the same issue I'm experiencing here. I'm not looking to target the last element in the column as it doesn't look like that's the problem. The problem seems to be the way columns applies the last-of-type or first-of-type pseudoselectors though.

It is not the selector in this case that is causing the inconsistent bottom spacing between ols. The issue is with CSS columns and margins.
